# Storing awk manipulation in variable

Tags: linux, bash, awk, text-processing

I have two text files in tab delimted format like following.

file_1

```
Entry_1 36372   36414   7   Aa  14956   36371   -
Entry_1 36471   36526   3   Aa  14956   36371   -
```

file_2

```
Entry_1 36365   36395   -
Entry_1 36366   36394   -
Entry_1 36367   36395   -
Entry_1 36368   36395   -
Entry_1 36394   36414   -
Entry_1 36471   36502   +
Entry_1 36483   36516   +
Entry_1 36495   36526   +
```

these two file contents were stored into two different variables. Now I would like extract the lines which has "+" symbol in column 4 and store it in the variable and later print it. But it throws me error message:

```
"line 4: /usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long"
"line 5: /usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long"
```

Here is my code which I tried

```
#!/bin/bash
value_1=$(cat file_1.txt);
value_2=$(cat file_2.txt);
plus="$(awk '$4=="+"' "$value_2" )"
minus="$(awk '$4=="-"' "$value_2")"
echo "$plus"
echo "$minus"
```

Kindly guide me. I would like extract those entries with which has "+" and "-" symbol and store in variable "$plus" and "$minus".

Comment: bedmap produces too much output, I guess.

Comment: @BjornA.Even if dont use bedmap also, I get the same error. Infact "awk" produces more big output.

Comment: @Chudar I think you should remove double quotes in plus/minus variable. Also, could you please add content of file_1.txt and file_2.txt with expected output.

Comment: @AbhijeetKasurde whatever the problem is, removing the delimiting quotes from a string will certainly not make things any better! Chudar the problem is there's too many strings in file_2.txt for your shell to pass to awk as a list of file names. [edit] your question to include sample content of file_1.txt and file_2.txt and tell us what you are trying to do and we can help you do itthe right way.

Comment: @BjornA. the input to awk has nothing to do with the output from bedmap which runs on the output from awk.

Comment: My  bad, I misread the text. Thanks for noticing

Comment: @EdMorton I have edited my question.Kindly guide me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

file.1 doesn't seem to be used.  To get the lines to a variable you can do this

```
$ plus=$(awk '$4=="+"' file.2)
```

similarly, you can do the same for negative sign.

```
$ echo "$plus"

Entry_1 36471   36502   +
Entry_1 36483   36516   +
Entry_1 36495   36526   +
```

if this is what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use one variable to use complete file for input as it will keep everything in one line and you will get result only for first line -

```
echo $value_1
Entry_1 36372 36414 7 Aa 14956 36371 - Entry_1 36471 36526 3 Aa 14956 36371 -
```

If your requirement is only to print the line in which you have "+" symbol as column 4 then you could try below code -

```
awk '$4 ~ "+" {print $0}' file_2.txt
```